# I get runtime error when editing a currently existing recordset in my vba module

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I am not that good in adodb.recordsets, however I have been using macros for many years. anyway, I have a vba code in which I use 3 recordsets to get the information from 3 different excel sheets. In the 4th recordset I gather the information of other recordsets and put them in different items using a field as a key.
When I use rst.movefirst and then 'do...loop while' for the first time in the code, everything is perfect.
Then, when I try to edit the values of the same recordset using another 'do...loop while' loop, I get runtime error '-214352571(80020005)'. I am not sure where the problem is:

```
Sub imp_currency_receipt()

i = 3
Sheets("Data Bank").Calculate

rw = Sheets("pipur").Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
rw2 = Sheets("CurAlloc").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rw3 = Sheets("ImpRec").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If rw = 1 Then
MsgBoxW Sheets("Data Bank").Range("H15").Value
Exit Sub
End If

If rw2 = 1 Then
MsgBoxW Sheets("Data Bank").Range("H35").Value
Exit Sub
End If

With ImportCurrencyReceipt
    
    ' for purchase registration information
    .hamk.Clear
    .sabNum.Clear
    .sabAmnt.Clear
    .SabCur.Clear
    .GhrAmnt.Clear
    .GhrCur.Clear
    
    ' for currency allocation information
    .Taham.Clear
    .Taval.Clear
    .Tacod.Clear
    
    ' for purchase information
    .Taham2.Clear
    .Taval2.Clear
    .Tacod2.Clear
    
    'for currency allocation and purchase control
    .kolCod.Clear
    .kolTakh.Clear
    .kolKhar.Clear
    .Tacod.Clear
    
    ' for purchase information
    .Taham2.Clear
    .Taval2.Clear
    .Tacod2.Clear
    
    'for currency allocation and purchase control
    .kolCod.Clear
    .kolTakh.Clear
    .kolKhar.Clear
End With
End With


Dim ss As ADODB.Recordset
Set ss = New ADODB.Recordset

With ss.Fields
    .Append "hamNum", adVariant
    .Append "SabtSefaresh", adVariant
    .Append "SabtAmnt", adDouble, 120
    .Append "SabtCur", adVariant
    .Append "GharAmnt", adDouble, 120
    .Append "GharCur", adVariant
    .Append "Show", adBoolean
End With
ss.Open

' fill ss recordset with the purchase information
For i = 2 To rw
ss.AddNew
ss!hamNum = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 12).Value
ss!SabtSefaresh = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 13).Value
ss!SabtAmnt = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 14).Value
ss!SabtCur = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 16).Value
ss!Gharamnt = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 15).Value
ss!GharCur = Sheets("pipur").Cells(i, 17).Value
ss!Show = True
Next i

Dim tak As New ADODB.Recordset
 tak.Fields.Append "Sham", adVariant
 tak.Fields.Append "Tval", adDouble
 tak.Fields.Append "Tcod", adVariant
 tak.Open
  
' fill tak recordset with currency allocation information
With Sheets("CurAlloc")
    For j = 2 To rw2
        tak.AddNew
        tak!Sham = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        tak!Tval = .Cells(j, 10).Value
        tak!tcod = .Cells(j, 11).Value
    Next j
End With

Dim khar As New ADODB.Recordset
 khar.Fields.Append "Tham", adVariant
 khar.Fields.Append "Tval2", adDouble
 khar.Fields.Append "Tcod2", adVariant
 khar.Open

' fill khar recordset with currecny purchase information
With Sheets("ImpRec")
    For k = 2 To rw3
        khar.AddNew
        khar!Tham = .Cells(k, 2).Value
        khar!Tval2 = .Cells(k, 8).Value
        khar!Tcod2 = .Cells(k, 12).Value
    Next k
End With

Dim kol As New ADODB.Recordset
 kol.Fields.Append "klham", adVariant
 kol.Fields.Append "klC", adVariant
 kol.Fields.Append "klT", adDouble
 kol.Fields.Append "klK", adVariant
 kol.Open
 
' initial filling of kol recordset
tak.MoveFirst
    Do
        kol.AddNew
        kol!klham = tak!Sham
        kol!klC = tak!tcod
        kol!klT = 0
        kol!klK = 0
        tak.MoveNext
    Loop While Not tak.EOF

' put currecny allocation and currency purchase information in KlT and klK fields of kol recordset
tak.MoveFirst
    Do
        khar.MoveFirst
        Do
            kol.MoveFirst
            Do
                If StrComp(kol!klham, tak!Sham) = 0 And StrComp(kol!klC, tak!tcod) = 0 Then
                    kol!klT = kol!klT + tak!Tval
                End If
                
                If StrComp(kol!klham, khar!Tham) = 0 And StrComp(kol!klC, khar!Tcod2) = 0 Then
                    kol!klK = kol!klK + khar!Tval2
                End If
                
                kol.MoveNext
            Loop While Not kol.EOF
            
        khar.MoveNext
        Loop While Not khar.EOF
        
    tak.MoveNext
    Loop While Not tak.EOF
    
    
    ' here we delete all purchases with no currency allocation code
    ss.MoveLast
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
        Do While Not ss.BOF
            tak.MoveFirst
            Do
                If StrComp(tak!Sham, ss!hamNum) = 0 Then found = True
                tak.MoveNext
            Loop While Not tak.EOF
            If found = False Then ss.Delete
            ss.MovePrevious
        Loop

' here I transfer the information from recordsets to the comboboxes in userform and then close the recordsets

With ImportCurrencyReceipt

    ss.MoveLast: ss.MoveFirst
    Do While Not ss.EOF
        .hamk.AddItem ss!hamNum
        .sabNum.AddItem ss!SabtSefaresh
        .sabAmnt.AddItem ss!SabtAmnt
        .SabCur.AddItem ss!SabtCur
        .GhrAmnt.AddItem ss!Gharamnt
        .GhrCur.AddItem ss!GharCur
        ss.MoveNext
    Loop
    If ss.State = 1 Then
        ss.Close
        Set ss = Nothing
    End If
    
    tak.MoveLast: tak.MoveFirst
    Do While Not tak.EOF
        .Taham.AddItem tak!Sham
        .Taval.AddItem tak!Tval
        .Tacod.AddItem tak!tcod
        tak.MoveNext
    Loop
    If tak.State = 1 Then
        tak.Close
        Set tak = Nothing
    End If

    khar.MoveLast: khar.MoveFirst
    Do While Not khar.EOF
        .Taham2.AddItem khar!Tham
        .Taval2.AddItem khar!Tval2
        .Tacod2.AddItem khar!Tcod2
        khar.MoveNext
    Loop
    If khar.State = 1 Then
        khar.Close
        Set khar = Nothing
    End If

    kol.MoveLast: kol.MoveFirst
    Do While Not kol.EOF
        .kolCod.AddItem kol!klC
        .kolTakh.AddItem kol!klT
        .kolKhar.AddItem kol!klK
        kol.MoveNext
    Loop
    If kol.State = 1 Then
        kol.Close
        Set kol = Nothing
    End If
End With
```

i get the error in line '.kolCod.AddItem kol!klC'. kol!KlT and kol!klK has value and are ok.Is there any limitation in the number of times that you can edit on or make change in a recordset?

[image]

I tried different ways of definition of the recordsets. I changed the code to the simplest form. But still something is missing or I don't know or cannot understand.

Comment: ImportCurrencyReceipt is a form, is that right?

Comment: *Is there any limitation in the number of times that you can edit on or make change in a recordset?* No there isn't, so its not that

Comment: Does the khar loop before the kol loop work ok? i.e. is there anything in the khar recordset? I'm just wondering why you get a crash on the kol loop particularly

Comment: Seems like runtime error '-214352571(80020005)' might be 'type mismatch', e.g. something to do with strings vs numbers

Comment: ImportCurrencyReceipt is a form. Yes

Comment: In fact upto the crash point everything works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime error runtime error '-214352571(80020005)' usually means Type Mismatch which means you've got some sort of problem with strings vs numbers or maybe a null value problem.

This line is giving the error:

```
.kolCod.AddItem kol!klC
```

... and I think this line is pulling a value from a recordset and adding it to a combobox as an item?

What is the value of kol!klC? Maybe it is null? In which case you could try this:

```
.kolCod.AddItem Nz(kol!klC,"(empty)")
```